# p2p framework видео

Tags: p2p

Посоветуйте фреймворк для потокового p2p-видео. Среда разработки не имеет значения.

Comment: Какой язык вас интересует?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое что приходит на ум Live P2P Video Streaming Framework, это в сторону Java.